# Window size is wrong or not setting in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

This is my first swing application. I'm trying to create an window and add a button. On clicking the button, it should display some value on the console. Everythign works fine, but the window is very small. I've specified 800*600, but then also the window size is small, that is its wrapping the button size only.

Here is  my code snippet:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Application");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
contentPane.add(new MyClass(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.setSize(800, 600);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Snippet from MyClass.java:

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
JButton button = new JButton("Button");
button.addActionListener(this);
add(button);
```

How to make the window size as 800*600?

Comment: this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193801/how-to-set-specific-window-frame-size-in-java-swing

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `frame.pack();` from your code.

**More information:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29

Comment: Thanks. Working as expected.

Comment: This is extremely bad advice and the wrong answer to select.

Answer (score 3):

The `pack()` method should always be called on a GUI based on a `JFrame`, so leave that in.  It reduces the GUI to the smallest size needed to display the components in it.  But don't go calling `setSize(Dimension)` after that, before checking it is *larger than the minimum size.*

Answer (score 0):

You are calling pack method. The api said: "It causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents"

You haven't specified the preferred size. Try it doing this:

frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)