# java: add an option "re-size window" in the contextual menu which appears when we right click on the restored window in the tool bar

Tags: java, resize, window, toolbar

First I apologize if my English is not very good. it's my 4th language :P:P.
I have a java program (which I run using NetBeans) that open a graphic window (application), when I restore this window then I do a right click on its button in the toolbar it shows a menu that contains a button to close the window (like it does for every window XD), I want to add another button or text to re-size the window to [30,30],(example: we add text "send window to [30,30]" and when we click on it it resize the window to 30,30) cause when I do a remote connection from home I can't see the window its big and it appears in the 2nd screen. I don't know how to write this in Java. I'll be grateful for any help. If I didn't explain the problem well please don't hesitate to ask me and i'll explain it other way.   :)
Thank you and have a lovely day everyone :):)

Comment: No need for a life story friend :). Just let us know what the problem is and provide a stack trace if you have one.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: haha sorry it's my 1st question here... I wanted to make sure that people understand what I'm saying :P

Comment: refer [how-to-set-specific-window-frame-size-in-java-swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193801/how-to-set-specific-window-frame-size-in-java-swing)

Comment: Thank you Madhan, but my main problem is how to add a button on the menu (right click in the restored window ...)

Comment: when commenting if your'e referring someone use @ personname.So that the person will be notified.and I couldn't get what you're saying can you post a screenshot of what you want to do

Comment: @Madhan the pic doesn't upload ... :/

Comment: @Madhan what I want to say is : in the toolbar when you do a right click at any application it shows a menu that have options like : close the window. I want to add to this menu a button that resets the application to (30,30).