# Why is Java GUI JFrame size different sizes on different operating systems?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, size

I am trying to design a GUI on Java but I'm having a problem that the size of the JFrame is appearing different on different operating systems.

Below you can see what the GUI should look like:

[image: Should look like this.]

Here you can see what it actually looks like on Linux:

[image: Looks like on Linux.]

And here you can see what it looks like on Mac:

[image: Looks like on Mac]

The code for the GUI is this:

```
private void initialize() {
    frmExample = new JFrame();
    frmExample.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    frmExample.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300);
    frmExample.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frmExample.setTitle("Example");
    frmExample.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 272);
    frmExample.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

I tried making changing `frmExample.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 272)` to `frmExample.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 300)` which worked for fixing the colour on this example project but if I want to have text along the bottom of the screen that won't be possible as the bottom of the screen on the GUI doesn't seam to be the same on all OSs.

Is there something I'm doing wrong that is causing this or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Try adding `frmExample.pack()` @see [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) on using `pack()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set specific window (frame) size in java swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193801/how-to-set-specific-window-frame-size-in-java-swing)

Comment: @EddieB Using `pack()` made the whole window as small as possible (literally 1px width). I assume it is because of the reason @camickr put in his answer.

Comment: Camickr included `getPreferredSize()` before `pack()` that's the difference.

Comment: @crossboy007, so did my reason fix the problem?

Comment: @camickr Yes. The BorderLayout won't allow me to set the GUI exactly how I initially wanted but using one of the other layout manages in the link you send will allow me to. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there something I'm doing wrong

```
frmExample.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

Don't use null layouts. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers so that components can be displayed properly on different Operating Systems.

> but if I want to have text along the bottom of the screen

So then your code should be something like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
{
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimenstion(400, 400);
    }
};

frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JLabel label = new JLabel("text at the bottom of the screen");
frame.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Now the pack() method will take in account the preferred size of all the components added to the frame and it will look correct on all platforms.

Read the section on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Download the demo code and play with it to understand the concept of how to use layout managers. Start with the demo on the BorderLayout.

Comment: how about if i added the set size under init components ?